# Disable widget with checkbutton?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

How can i disable an entry using a checkbutton... i got this but it doens't work (python 2.7.1)...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class Principal(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        foo = ""    
        nac = ""

        global ck1
        nac = IntVar()      
        ck1 = Checkbutton(root, text='Test',variable=nac, command=self.naccheck)
        ck1.pack()

        global ent
        ent = Entry(root, width = 20, background = 'white', textvariable = foo, state = DISABLED)       
        ent.pack()

    def naccheck(self):
        if nac == 1:
            ent.configure(state='disabled')
        else:
            ent.configure(state='normal')       

app=Principal()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made foo and nac member variable of the Principal class

```
    ...
    self.foo = StringVar()
    self.foo.set("test")
    self.nac = IntVar()
    ...
```

Then in naccheck() reference self.nac

```
    def naccheck(self):
        if self.nac == 1:
            ent.configure(state='disabled')
            self.nac = 0
        else:
            ent.configure(state='normal')
            self.nac = 1
```

Dont forget to change ck1's variable = self.nac
and ent's textvariable = self.foo.

Also, you might want to make ck1 and ent member variable, as you might have problems referencing them later with naccheck()

Those changes worked fine on my Python2.7

Answer (score 3):

There are many small things wrong with your code. For one, `Principle` inherits from `tk.Tk` but you don't import Tkinter under the name `tk`.

Second, you don't need global variables. You should use instance variables instead.

Third, since "nac" is a `IntVar` you need to use the `get` method to get the value.

Finally, you are using `foo` as the value of the `textvariable` attribute but you are using an ordinary value. It needs to be a Tk variable (eg: `StringVar`)

Here's a version of your code with those things fixed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class Principal(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.foo = tk.StringVar()
        self.nac = tk.IntVar()      
        ck1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Test',variable=self.nac, command=self.naccheck)
        ck1.pack()

        self.ent = tk.Entry(root, width = 20, background = 'white', 
                            textvariable = self.foo, state = tk.DISABLED)       
        self.ent.pack()

    def naccheck(self):
        if self.nac.get() == 1:
            self.ent.configure(state='disabled')
        else:
            self.ent.configure(state='normal')       

app=Principal()
root.mainloop()
```

By the way, whether you do `from Tkinter import *` or `import Tkinter as tk` is a matter of style. I like the latter because it leaves no doubt which module contains the name of the class or constant. Doing an `import *` can cause problems if you import something with a name that clashes with other code in your file.

Comment: thanks... i'm using "Tkinter as tk" cause i like some widgets with the old style  (not ttk)...

Comment: @Hairo: I don't understand your comment. How you import has no effect on whether you use ttk or original widgets. Plus, you say you're using `import Tkinter as tk` but clearly in your example you are not. Your example shows `from Tkinter import *`

Comment: ohh, sorry it's just an example... in the whole code i used "import Tkinter as tk" too, so if i add "tk.Entry" get the old style, and if just use "Entry" get the ttk style...